# How to trigger a github webhook from Dropbox

Tags: github-actions, webhooks, dropbox, dropbox-api, github-webhook

Dropbox gives the possiiblity to create a webhook [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) that is sent when a file is added to a folder. Reading the [doc](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks) it seems that you can't configure much the information that are sent and there is also a verification procedure the client should match.

The client is github, in particular I want to trigger a job in continuos integration (github actions) when a file is added in a Dropbox folder.

I solved used a third party service, in this case [Zapier](https://zapier.com/), which is similar to IFTTT, but it is not free to send raw http post (which actually it is the simpler thing they offer...)

Is there an easy way to achieve what I meant, without using a third party service, and without querying Dropbox continuosly to check for new files?

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is `repository_dispatch` events in GitHub Actions
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch

Comment: @tj-cappelletti I am already using it. The point is that Dropbox requires the client to pass a verification step, when it need to return a specific answer. In addition you can't change the payload of the request sent by Dropbox.